# Switch Submit button once form submitted?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, forms, submit

I have a big form on my website that takes a little longer than usual to load the next page.

Is there an easy way to switch my 'Submit' button to an animated "Loading..." graphic once clicked? Just so the user knows we're still working on the submission.

Many thanks for any pointers,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically achieved by hidihg or disabling the submti button **before** making the ajax call and then reverting the change on the complete handler. Example:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#loading_anim').show();

    $.ajax(
        ...,
        complete: function() {
            $('#submit').show();
            $('#loading_anim').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

The complete handler is useful in this case as it is run both in the case of a successful response and an error response.

Comment: Many thanks, a'r. Sadly I'm not in a position to test right now, but will do shortly. Thanks again for your speedy reply. Will let you know how I go :D

Comment: jQuery's .submit() may be more appropriate! And the AJAX call shouldn't be required, since it's only a regular form submisison.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use jQuery's [submit event handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  $('#loading-overlay').show();
  return false;
});
```